# How the electrons from electrode play a role in stimulating the neuron?

Tags: electrophysiology

I am trying to understand how a neuron fires action potential after being stimulated via electrode (extracellular stimulation). GHK equation gives the membrane potential,which is -70 mV when neuron is at rest. When the membrane potential increases to -55 mV, it fires AP. But then an electrode gives electrons, which do not appear in the equation. Then how the electrons from electrode play a role in stimulating the neuron? Also,   is there a way to calculate how many electrons or how much current would be required to stimulate a  neuron?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/53317/why-does-an-electric-shock-contract-the-muscle/).