# How strong of an electric field is dangerous to adult humans?

Tags: muscles, electromuscular

Given that "a potential difference is introduced over the membrane, the associated electric field induces a conformational strong in the potassium channel" is required for our muscles to move, how powerful of an electric field is required to cause our muscles (including the heart) to fire irregularly?  How much stronger would it have to be to kill someone?

https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/53330/7973

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_ion_channel

(No, I'm not an "electrosensitive" afraid of cellphones or high-tension wires.)

Thanks

Comment: You can find out about that from google... Electric fields are not large or small. They are powerful or weak, they vary in voltage, wattage etc. A high voltage signal can be like a bullet, small and very light and penetrating anything. A low voltage signal can be like a train going very slowly, able to heat metal red but having trouble going through it.

Comment: @com.prehensible what exactly would I Google?

Comment: It's a fascinating topic, and there's a mass of research on it: google: minimal electric current to cause death, first page is: https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/JackHsu.shtml ... change to "minimal electric current to cause death nerves" have info on nerve physiology: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/ ... "conduction electric through body" with specific topics, cardiac arrest, nerves... Pacemakers are designed to last a long time, a 10 gram battery can supply enough energy to change the rythm of the heart for 20 years.

Answer (score -1):

Research published by WSU Professor Emeritus of Biochemistry and Basic Medical Sciences, Dr. Martin Pall, bears directly on your question about potassium channels.

https://www.researchgate.net/project/microwave-frequency-radiation-acts-via-voltage-gated-calcium-channel-activation

He has concluded that weak EMFs cause cascading health impacts that derive from false electrical signaling of voltage-gated ion channels, and that these impacts include heart disease and the dreaded social bugbear elctrosensitivity (microwave disease).